# Употребление причастного оборота

Tags: грамматика

Предложение с ошибкой: *"Одному из героев романа, **ищущим** смысл жизни, открывается путь к внутренней свободе".*
Ответ в ключах: *"Одному из героев романа, **ищущих** смысл жизни, открывается путь к внутренней свободе".*
Почему нет такого варианта в ответах: **"Одному из героев романа, **ищущему** смысл жизни, открывается путь к внутренней свободе*"?

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки можно переставить оборот:

*Одному из **ищущих** смысл жизни героев романа открывается путь к внутренней свободе*.

Comment: но ищущему тоже ведь можно. Хотя, искал смысл, а нашел путь к свободе - такая себе логика.

Comment: Логика, может, и сомнительная, но все это касается семантики, а не грамматики.  В этом же варианте нужно выбрать правильную грамматическую форму.  Можно еще так: Одному из многих героев, ищущих...

Comment: В этом же варианте нужно правильно обозначить грамматическую форму - я вас не узнаю.

Comment: Разве я так написала?)

Comment: То есть возможен только второй вариант?

Comment: Здесь семантику надо учитывать. Если только один герой ищет смысл жизни, то ищущему. А если таких героев много, то ищущих.  Но скорее многие ищут такой смысл.

Comment: Просто непонятно, почему не может согласовываться с местоимением...

Comment: Может, но надо смысл учитывать. Если смысл неизвестен, но более вероятно "ищущих".  Трудно представить, что никто другой не ищет смысла своей жизни.

Comment: @Sharon, ваш вариант тоже верный. Но в примере есть существительное в ед.ч. Согласование-то должно быть с ним.

Comment: Серж, я выбрала согласование по СМЫСЛУ, разве такое невозможно? Многие герои романа ищут смысл жизни, и вот одному из них открывается путь к внутренней свободе. Есть согласование по ФОРМЕ: только один герой в романе ищет смысл жизни, ему-то и открывается этот путь. А остальные что же, совсем никакие? Смыслом жизни не интересуются, хотя и такое бывает.

Comment: Забавная цитата по этой ТЕМЕ из книги Е. Лукина:  "Тут в прихожей случилась некая суматоха, давка, толкотня – и дверь распахнулась, явив в проеме того самого посетителя, которому типа хотели акции впарить. Надумал, значит… – В чём СМЫСЛ жизни? – выпалил он с порога. – Чьей? – Моей! – Отсутствует. Следующий…"

Comment: Sharon, зачем менять предложение?